# Navigation properties in HTML client with sql server data source

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2013

Visual Studio Lightswitch 2013
Using a sql server data source, we have an entity A with n:1 relations to other entities B,C, ...; so, entity A have some navigation properties of type B,C,...

With HTML client, after issued a query for entity A, properties B,C,... are all undefined. This happens in the following cases:

- added a data item to screen with related entities included (used 'manage included data' feature in 'edit query'); used load method on data item object to programmatically load the visual collection data (ex: screen.Customers.load(false).then(...) )
- used the data service programmatically with 'expand' method (ex: myapp.activeDataWorkspace.SqlData.Customers.expand("Address").execute().then(... )

Inspecting the returned data, the 'hidden' property '_' of every entity instance have the foreign key fields correctly loaded.

Note: inspecting the requested url with Fiddler reveals that the query is correct; inspecting the sql server issued query (though Sql Server Profiler) reveals that the query includes the related data. Issuing the OData query reveals that all data are returned.
It seems that client side, when data is deserialized, navigation entities are not materialied.

Trying the same approaches with intrinsic data source works (navigation properties are loaded as expected).

Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Further testing reveals that only foreign keys to int columns are correctly handled as navigation properties.
Examples:

- 'wrong' case:
  Table A, primary key = nvarchar field
  Table B with field B.f1 of type nvarchar as foreign key to A

  A navigation property is defined but not materialized at client side
- 'correct' case
  Table C, primary key = int field
  Table D with field D.f1 of type int as foreign key to C

  A navigation property is defined and materialzed at client side